# How to loop a variable in tcl

Tags: loops, variables, tcl

I am new to tcl. I have some doubt regarding can i loop a variable in tcl.

I have set variable called handle i.e

```
set handle [pcap open -ip 192.168.1.3]
```

This creates a handle pcap0. I wanna know whether can i loop this variable in tcl so that at a time i can create a ten handles.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: lists and arrays.

### 1. Using a list

In Tcl, a list is a *value* that contains a sequence of other (arbitrary) values. You can add things to the end of a list in a variable with `lappend`, and iterate over the list with `foreach`.

```
foreach ipaddress {192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 192.168.1.5 ...} {
    lappend handles [pcap open -ip $ipaddress]
}

foreach handle $handles {
    # Do something with $handle here
}
```

### 2. Using an array

In Tcl, an array is a *composite variable backed by an associative map* (you look things up by any value you want, not necessarily a number). They can work quite well with lists.

```
set the_addresses {192.168.1.3 192.168.1.4 192.168.1.5 ...}
foreach ipaddress $the_addresses {
    set handle($ipaddress) [pcap open -ip $ipaddress]
}

foreach ipaddress $the_addresses {
    # Do something with $handle($ipaddress) here
}
```

Which option is best depends on the details of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I am well aware for this syntax this means i need to define all the ip in list or array.In my case i am creating 10 handles with same IP i.e 192.168.1.4 .Can you suggest me any syntax or proc in tcl.

Answer (score 0):

Donal gave what seemed to be the complete answer, if the IP address is the same, simply do:

```
set handles ""
set ipaddress 192.168.1.3
for {set i 0} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
    lappend handles [pcap open -ip $ipaddress]
}

foreach handle $handles {
    # Do something with $handle here
}
```